# How to solve Helmholtz equation with nonhomogeneous boundary conditions?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'd like to solve the two-dimensional problem in the rectangular domain $[0,L] \times [0,b]$ ($x\in[0,L], y\in[0,b]$):

$\nabla^2 u + k^2 u=0$

with the following boundary conditions:

$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}(0)=\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}(b)=0$

$u(0)=g(y)\neq const$

$u(L)=const$

Assuming $u=X(x)Y(y)$, I am having problems with the solution for $X(x)$. Can anyone help?

Comment: Why can't it be solved by separation of variables?

Comment: I am using separation of variables, and I got $Y(y)=cos\dfrac{n \pi y}{b}$. The problem is with solving the X(x) part.